# iOS Migration from UIWebView to WKWebView for JavaScript POST

Tags: ios, swift, payment, 3d-secure

I am implementing a secure payment solution in Native iOS App in Swift.

Basically when i start a payment request , in response i get a "PaReq" and "ACSURL" in the response, if the payment card is 3D Check enrolled.

Then i need to do java script POST.

And once the user completed action , i need to extract "PaRes" and send it in next service call.

Here is the working solution in Objective-C using UIWebView.I want to achieve same thing in Swift Using WKWebView as UIWebView is deprecated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIWebView *webView=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.secureViewContainer.frame.size.width ,self.secureViewContainer.frame.size.height)];
    webView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    NSString *termURL = @"https://www.apple.com";

    self.webViewURL = @"";
    self.webViewHTMLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><form name='redirectToIssuerForm' id='redirectToIssuerForm' action='%@' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='PaReq' value='%@' /><input type='hidden' name='TermUrl' value='%@' /><input type='hidden' name='MD' value='' /><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Click here to continue' /></form><script>function submitForm(){document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('submitButton').click();} window.onload = (function(){submitForm();});</script></body></html>",self.acsurl,self.pareq,termURL];

    [webView loadHTMLString:self.webViewHTMLString baseURL:nil];

}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    if([webView.request.URL.absoluteString isEqualToString:@"about:blank"]){
        [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"submitForm()"];
    }
}

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    if([ [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",request.URL] isEqualToString:@"https://www.apple.com/"]){ 

    NSData *data = request.HTTPBody;

    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"\n\n\n  3D Secure - dataString: %@", dataString);

        return NO;
    }
    else{

        return YES;

    }
}
```

Here is what i have tried to migrate to Swift Using WKWebView :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let customFrame = CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize.init(width: 0.0, height: self.secureViewContainer.frame.size.height))
    self.webView = WKWebView (frame: customFrame , configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    self.secureViewContainer.addSubview(webView)          
}
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    let termURLString = "https://www.apple.com"
    var paReqString = response.PaRequest
    var acsurlString = response.ACSURL

    // create HTML String 

    let webViewHTMLString = String(format:"<html><body><form name='redirectToIssuerForm' id='redirectToIssuerForm' action='%@' method='post'><input type='hidden' name='PaReq' value='%@' /><input type='hidden' name='TermUrl' value='%@' /><input type='hidden' name='MD' value='' /><input type='submit' id='submitButton' value='Click here to continue' /></form><script>function submitForm(){document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display='none'; document.getElementById('submitButton').click();} window.onload = (function(){submitForm();});</script></body></html>",acsurlString,paReqString,termURLString)

        // Load HTML String
        webView.loadHTMLString(webViewHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
 }

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    if webView.url?.absoluteString == "about:blank" {

        webView.evaluateJavaScript("submitForm()", completionHandler: {
            result in

            print("\n\n\n Result - \(result)\n\n\n")

        })
    }

}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    if let url = navigationAction.request.url,url.absoluteString.hasPrefix("https://www.apple.com/") {
        let data = navigationAction.request.httpBody

        print("\n\n  data : \(String(describing: data))")

        decisionHandler(.cancel)
        return
    }
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

The problem is both "Result" and "data" are nil.

1 : Will i get the java script result in webView(_:decidePolicyFor:decisionHandler:)  (or) in webView:didFinishNavigation: ?

2 : In UIWebView working solution i am able to change termURL to any url like "https://www.apple.com" , still i am able get Data fine , Can someone explain me how this Javascript POST works ?

3 : Please point me to a guide/tutorial to understand more about JavaScript and Native iOS App interaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're on the right track. [I recently wrote an article on this subject, and that should explain everything you need.](https://medium.com/@JillevdWeerd/creating-links-between-wkwebview-and-native-code-8e998889b503)

First of all, if you want to send something to the native code from your javascript code, you need to use `window.webkit` in your javascript code. You'll need to implement the WKScriptMessageHandler and WKNavigationDelegate in your swift code, and implement this function:

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    //This function handles the events coming from javascript.
    //We can access properties through the message body, like this:
    guard let response = message.body as? String else { return }
    print(response)
}
```

More information on this is in the article.

All the sending you will be doing will go through `webview.evaluateJavascript()`. Make sure the javascript function works, because webkit errors won't show up in your Xcode console. You'll have to implement a custom messageHandler for that.

Comment: I just want to use the httpBody of the request in `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)` as `navigationAction.request.httpBody` but I am getting `nil` all the time. I am new to Javascrip. can you pease help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

1. You get the result in `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!)`, BUT **only inside the completionHandler closure**, not function-wide.
2. As I see it `termURL` is just the content of some hidden input field of the form. Its value is passed when submitting the form - but it has nothing to do with where it is being submitted to.
3. This seems a good, but basic [intro into WkWebViews](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/). And there's this blog post about [WkWebView JavaScript Quirks](http://swiftgazelle.com/tag/wkwebview/).